# Must-do regarding on site SEO

Tags: seo, google

I read a lot of articles regarding on site SEO. I focused mostly on Yoast SEO recommendations (since i'm using Wordpress) and Google guidelines.

- Structured headings
- Optimized site speed
- Breadcrumbs
- Updated sitemap
- No-follow all external links
- No index pages with content that is not unique

What else should i do, to make my site more SEO optimized? Any recommended reading is welcome :)

After making those changes, how soon should i notice some positive changes in page rankings?

Answer (score 0):

for now just three points from my side, relating to the actual content of your site:

- machine- and human-readable URLs, containing your most important keywords.
  Put the important ones first
- site title and description, containing your most important keywords. Again: put your most important keywords first
- on-site linking – that means linking from within an article/story to another article/story on your wensite (not only a generic list "related links")

This could probably be an endless list – however I'll just undeline one more point that is important to me and has been working in the past: focus on your content and always have your readers in mind.

Even if you're *only* looking for technical solutions, maybe you're not even writing the content yourself – but anyways: without content that matters to your readers, all technical efforts may be useless. Focus on a subject, gather some keywords that matter to you and probably also matter to your readers around that subject – and place those keywords where ever appropriate. And this also has a technical aspect: Search Engines (Google) are keen on finding and listing content that matters to their users too.